# VS code turns 'it' into 'hasUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback'. How to disable this?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, jasmine

I am going through a book on Test Driven Development in React. I've never written JavaScript tests before. The author presents the following Jest code in a file titled `calc.test.js`:

```
var add = require('./calc.js')

describe('calculator',function() {
  it('add two numbers',function() {
    expect(add(1,2)).toEqual(3)
  })
})
```

but VS code automatically translates it to:

```
const { hasUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback } = require('process')
const { isTypedArray } = require('util/types')
var add = require('./calc.js')
describe('calculator', function () {
    isTypedArray('add two numbers', function () {
        hasUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback(add(1, 2).toEqual(3))
    })
})
```

The author states that his version uses syntax "borrowed from" jasmine. Is that why VS Code changed it? How do I turn this feature off? Jest is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like vscode tries to autocomplete `it` and `expect`, and auto imports the modules `process` and `utils/types`.
Even though manually importing isn't required per the [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/api):

> In your test files, Jest puts each of these methods and objects into
> the global environment. You don't have to require or import anything
> to use them. However, if you prefer explicit imports, you can do
> import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals'.

You can silence vscode warnings by explicitly importing:

```
import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals'
```